# uneven spacing in label for a word search puzzle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a word search using a rectangular array and displaying the array in a label in Visual Studio.

So far I have a wordSearch class with a ToString() method that displays the array like a word search.

I call the toString when I click on a button to have the label's text as the toString result, but the spacing is not equal.
Here is my ToString() method:

```
public override string ToString()
{ 
    string result ="";
    for (int row = 0; row < puzzle.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < puzzle.GetLength(1); column++)
        {
            result = result + string.Format("{0,-4}", puzzle[row, column]);
        }
        result = result + "\n";
    }
    return result;
```

Autosize is true for my label and the text align setting is middle left.
This is what it looks like:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/123846717@N08/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use a monospaced font (like consolas)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

edit : somes examples to pick from

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Font that has the same width for each character.
You can find a list here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces